# Disable Access Message "You are about to paste x records"?

Tags: vba, ms-access, paste

I have a Datasheet Form holding data for a table. When data in a row is changed and the row is left, or new records are inserted and the row is left, or rows are deleted, there are events (BeforeUpdate, AfterUpdate, etc) that handle storing Audit records and pasting to an Audit Table. The current situation I am dealing with is this:

-The User copies Excel Data A1:A2, then highlights  the vertical cells values (as seen in the picture below), then pastes the data.

[Paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWB8K.png)

Even after leaving 'Application.Echo True' and 'DoCmd.SetWarnings True' in the AfterUpdate event, I still get the message "You are about to paste x records. Are you sure you want to paste?". If the User selects No, then the Audit table contains erroneous data. How do I disable this notification, but turn notifications back on after the procedure has completed? Is there an equivalent of BeforeDelConfirm but for Paste confirmation?

Comment: This appears as several questions mixed together. I'd like to help but now sure about your problems. Please focus on one problem at a time and explain it. Then the next. If they are related describe how.

Comment: @Felix This is one question, I was just giving context for those trying to replicate.. Where  in the form events can you trap the Access Error Message 8520 "You are about to paste | record(s).@Are you sure you want to paste these records?@@19@@@2"?

Answer (score 0):

A quick way would be to open the form in design mode.
Open the properties box. 
Select / click on a section (e.g. the little black square in the left top corner of the form) to get the properties for the form
Select the Event tab and in 'Before update' select [Event Procedure].
On the right of the line click ... which will take you to VBA editor
in the module insert:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
End Sub
```

Save form and try.

If you need other dialogs appear later, you will need to enable it back.
One event could be OnClick (or choose one that you see best work for you). In which case do it similarly as described above for the event that would be best for you to trigger the dialogs functionality back and enter in the given module:

```
Private Sub Form_Click()
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Eventually, you can add a customized menu item or icon to your Access tool bar that will allow you to toggle the dialogs on/off at a click.

Comment: I just realized I ran a module which left .SetWarnings True.  My question now however is , which event would realistically fire after edit,insert,delete operations where i could turn warnings back on that would not affect the pop-up message? For example, I tried turning them back on in the OnCurrent event, but then when I pasted 2 cells of data as described in my original post it hits the following event: BeforeUpdate -> AfterUpdate -> BeforeUpdate -> AfterUpdate -> OnCurrent ->  "Are you sure you want to paste". I cant use the OnClick as record selectors are hidden.

Comment: One idea may be using OnTimer. You could enable timer at the end of your editing event. The timer would kick in after e.g 2 seconds, enable your dialogs and disable itself (the timer).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to turn off the confirm message for this form, use the activate/deactivate form events.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Activate()
   Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", 0
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Deactivate()
    Application.SetOption "Confirm Record Changes", 1
End Sub
```

This just deactivates the confirm message instead off all messages with `DoCmd.SetWarnings False`, when form is active:

List of options: [Set Options from Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/set-options-from-visual-basic)